# My target .Net framework for windows XP

Tags: .net

I need target my C# app to run on at-least windows XP or above

The application is targeted to home users, some of them would be reluctant to install additional framework on their computer,

So I am trying to target a framework which most of users have.

My application can even work with 2.0, however some third-party libs (NetSparkle in my case) which I need to use require a target of atleast 4.0

Is targeting framework 4 a good choice, given I need my app to be ready to run on windows XP ?

Thanks,

Comment: What kind of answers do you expect? _"Is targeting framework 4 a good choice"_ **Yes\No**?

Comment: Yes, no, oh I don't know. Seeing as you are going to have to replace everything dependent on 4 before you can target 2, why not release at 4 and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need .NET 4 for your requirements, you'll have little choice.  You'll need to target at least 4.0 to use those libraries.

That being said, .NET 4 was not included with Windows XP, so you'll want to include, at a minimum, the web framework installer with your application deployment.  This allows users who do not have .NET 4 to install your application and run it properly.

Personally, I find imposing a framework installation far less restrictive than trying to duplicate functionality from a library you could otherwise use, so I have little fear of imposing .NET 4 on users, but that's my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Reed, I guess I will go with web framework installer, but I am not sure how to bundle this and conditionally invoke framework installation, any reference for further details would be helpful

Comment: @Jane Most setup program generation software will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP does not come with any version of the .Net Framework.  Whichever version you target would have to be installed on an XP machine before your app could be used.  I would say that it's more probable that an older version of the framework would already be installed, but there's no guarantee obviously.

I would base your decision more on what features you needed, and include an installer for the framework that your software needs.